# How do I block an object from casting shadows on it?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

Say I have a planet and space station. If I made them according to correct scale and placed them respectively, no problems would be. But in the scene they`re close, and station casts a shadow on planet. How can I block it? Eevee.

PS I looked at what system thinks as similar questions but have not find the answer. At least not for the modern day Blender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the light settings, in the shadow section, you can change the max distance value if you're using a sun light, or change the clip start value if you're using any other type of light.

[image]

[image]